# Include and reference xml config files in a maven test-jar

Tags: java, testing, maven

I am generating an app-tests.jar file with maven:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/testsetup/**</include>
                            <include>**/config/**</include>                             
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

How can I access those config files from the test classes in the app-tests.jar archive?

```
    System.setProperty("test.config", "config/test_config.xml");
    getConfiguration("test.config");
```

I use

org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.DefaultConfigurationBuilder(String fileName)

to load the configuration.

This does not work!
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `getConfiguration` does it's hard to say. But you should probably use `"classpath:config/test_config.xml"` if it's using Spring to load a resource.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
    "jar:file:/d:/temp/app-tests.jar!/config/test_config.xml"
this works